# Best Approach - Show Hide DB Feedback Alert

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a user model input form using Bootstrap/mySQLi/php and I have managed to create user feedback for whether their input has been added to the database or not.

However,  I want to know which is the best approach to conditionally hiding or showing elements;

[Failure!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KqcZ.jpg)
[Success!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PItK.jpg)

Clearly though I don't want them to be displayed at the same time,  these errors exist in their own `<div>`:

```
<div id="database_success" name="database_success" class="alert alert-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
  <strong>Success!</strong> <?php echo $successmessage; ?>
</div>


<!-- Create Failure Alert Initially Hidden-->
 <div  id="database_error" class="alert alert-danger" type="hidden"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>
  <strong>Error!</strong> <?php echo $errormessage; ?>
</div>
```

Essentially I just want to show whichever variable hasn't returned 0.

I guess this requires JavaScript, but if anybody can point in the right direction that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `if else` statement

```
<?php if($successmessage != '0') { ?>
    <div id="database_success" name="database_success" class="alert alert-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
        <strong>Success!</strong> <?php echo $successmessage; ?>
    </div>
<?php } else if($errormessage != '0') { ?>
    <!-- Create Failure Alert Initially Hidden-->
    <div  id="database_error" class="alert alert-danger" type="hidden"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>
        <strong>Error!</strong> <?php echo $errormessage; ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Adding on to that, the main difference between the two is the class (`alert-danger` or `alert-success`) and the icon. What you could do instead is generalise the message to an array with a `message`, `state` and `icon` and display that if it has been set. If you would want to also add a warning, or info alert you would have to keep duplicating your code.